# Command prompt window can't close in .NET when calling Process.Start() method

Tags: .net

I have created a Console application. In this application if any exception happens i tried to restart the exe by using Process.Start() method. The problem is that while executing this particular line of code a command prompt window will **open and close**. This process happens again and again. This is the code i have tried to restart the exe.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        Info.Arguments = "/C \"" + Application.StartupPath + "\\AppRestart.exe" + "\"";
        Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        Info.CreateNoWindow = false;
        Info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        Process.Start(Info);
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a command window to run a console application.

```
ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo();
Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
Info.CreateNoWindow = false;
Info.FileName = "\"" + Application.StartupPath + "\\AppRestart.exe" + "\"";
Process.Start(Info);
Environment.Exit(0);
```

Actually, if you want to run something inside the command window you need to add the /C or /K flags otherwise the cmd.exe runs but doesn't execute anything.
In this case, if you really need  to hide the command window you could set the

```
 Info.CreateNoWindow = true;
 Info.UseShellExecute = false;
```

but, it is not necessary to run your console application in a command window. It will create its own console to run into.

A side note, if the code of AppRestart is the one showed above, you enter an infinite loop. At first launch it throws unconditionally an exception, caught in the catch clause that restart the same application with the same unconditionally throw in the main code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if(conditionNotToThrow == false)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
     }
     else
     {
         // the code to resolve the problem for which this application has been made
     }
}
```

Comment: I am try by using only process.start.Now the same thing happening again and again

Comment: Wait, do you really have that code in main? I mean `throw ArgumentNullException`, if you really have it without any condiftional then no wonder that your application enters an infinite loop

Comment: exactly..Now i got the point..I put break point on the starting of the main method..I am expecting the break point hitting. actually i forgot one thing that when we calling the exe directly without attaching the process it will never hit on the break point.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you're in fact starting `cmd.exe` (the Windows command line processor) which is a console application.

Try

```
ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo();
Info.FileName = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath,"AppRestart.exe");
Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
Info.CreateNoWindow = false;
Process.Start(Info);
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        Info.Arguments = "/C \"" + Application.StartupPath + "\\AppRestart.exe" + "\"";
        //Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        //Info.CreateNoWindow = false;

        // set window hidden
        Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        // set window hidden

        Info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        Process.Start(Info);
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest updating your answer to highlight what you've actually changed - it's not immediately clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart directly your exe without using cmd.exe